# How can I split a string into three parts after space and turn the values to doubles?

Tags: c++

I am currently gathering info from a BLE device. I made a thread earlier where I successfully split a string consisting of 5 letters to their unique chars.

However from this BLE device i will also send some different information from time to time where I send 3 different values with a space after each one. So for example looking like this:

`-0.1 0.51 0.07`

So what I want to do now is to store this three numbers in different doubles and what I have done so far is this:

First i store the recieved message:

```
String recievedMessage;

recievedMessage += (char)BTLEserial.read();
```

Now I have to determine if the value sent is the 5 letters or if it is the numbers with a space between each value.

```
if (recievedMessage.length() > 5) //so if the recievedmessage is more than 5 words then it is the 3 values that is being sent.
{
char * charTheMessage = recievedMessage.c_str();
char *str;
str = strtok(charTheMessage, " ");

double one = str[0];
double two = str[1];
double three = str[2];

Serial.println (one);
Serial.println (two);
Serial.println (three);

}

if (recievedMessage.length() == 5)
{
 //http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36227/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-multiple-parts/36237?noredirect=1#comment72313_36237
//Here I split the letters into 5 different values if the value sent is 5. 
}
```

But this values do not come out right when I print them in the serial monitor. I have also read that strtok is not reliable when data is sent fast so is strtok the right way to go you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Strtok returns the *first* token in the string only. You then have to convert that to a double yourself. You then call strtok again with NULL as the source string to get the next token. And so on.

I have written a good strtok example on here already. Look around, you may find it.

Comment: I am out and about and using my phone right now so can't do a complex answer.

Comment: Here is one example: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/strtok-problem-while-parsing-string

Comment: Trying it right now! :) Will strncmp also work with spaces?

Comment: strncmp sees space as just another character

Comment: ok, let me try to see if i can work it out!

Comment: Ok. I get some more accurate results now (progress!) but in the while loop I only reach the "FIRST" if statement. Check post for updated code:

Comment: Nvm I fixed it! I just used the if-statement and removed the else if functions and inside the if statement i just added a simple int that increases in order to separate the three results